Algolia - Symfony 7 bundle installation problem
I can not get the Symfony / Algolia bundle to install with Symfony 7, php 8.2 and MAMP Pro on mac. I have all the dependencies they require (Symfony > 3.4 and php > 7.2). Running (right from Algolia docs)
composer require algolia/search-bundle

results in
 Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-mysql_xdevapi * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mysql_xdevapi extension.
  Problem 2
    - algolia/search-bundle[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.12] require symfony/framework-bundle ~2.5 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v2.5.0, ..., v2.8.52] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (7.0.*).
    - algolia/search-bundle 1.0.13 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.5|~3.0 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v2.5.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (7.0.*).
    - algolia/search-bundle[2.0.0, ..., 2.2.0, 4.0.0, ..., 4.1.2] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - algolia/search-bundle[3.0.0, ..., 3.4.0] require symfony/filesystem ^3.4.0 || ^4.0.0 -> found symfony/filesystem[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.42] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - algolia/search-bundle[5.0.0, ..., 5.2.1] require symfony/filesystem ^3.4 || ^4.0 || ^5.0 -> found symfony/filesystem[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.42, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.40] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - algolia/search-bundle[6.0.0, ..., 6.0.1] require symfony/filesystem ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/filesystem[v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.40, v6.0.0, ..., v6.4.8] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires algolia/search-bundle * -> satisfiable by algolia/search-bundle[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.13, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, ..., 3.4.0, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 5.0.0, ..., 5.2.1, 6.0.0, 6.0.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0/conf/php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-mysql_xdevapi` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require algolia/search-bundle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require algolia/search-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Ok, ext-mysql_xdevapi is needed. It seems to be installable via PECL, but i did not succeed (very few documentation online - my mistake? maybe...)
Problem 2 is nonsense to me, it requres symfony 2.5, what is poutdated by... 10 years?
Probably it is my fault, but after 2 days of googleing i have no idea. Any help is most useful. Thank you.

It looks like seach-bundle, does not support Symfony 7 yet.
https://github.com/algolia/search-bundle/issues/377

... and it was written 7 months ago... :(( not good. Unfortunately Algolia is not answering my ticket... Not too professional. Anyway, thank you for your research. Stay safe.
